# Can someone help me find an explicit formula for these polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, recursion, riemann-zeta

I was studying the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), and I stumbled on the polynomials given by the recursion formula:

$$P_{k+1} = x(1-x) P'_k+x(k+1)P_k\; \text{ and }\; P_0=1$$

Can someone help me find an explicit formula for them?

For context: If you differentiate $1 / (1-x)$ (harmonic series), multiply by $x$ and evaluate at $-1$, you get the negative of the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) calculated at $-1$.

We can differentiate and multiply by $x$ several times to get other values of the eta function. Let's define $f_{k+1} = x f'_k$, $f_0=-1/(1-x)$. I thought about looking only at the numerator, defining $P_k = -(1 -x)^{k+1} f_k$. This way I got the said recursion formula.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide more context, instead of just saying that you stumbled on the polynomials while studying the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Two typos. The recursion is $P_{k+1} = x(1-x) P'_k+x(k+1)P_k.$ Also the $P_n(x)$ is the **negative** of the polynomials associated to [OEIS sequence A008292](https://oeis.org/A008929) Eulerian numbers.

Comment: Thank you Somos, I corrected the question!